# Spree Allow admin login with different roles added in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, spree, spree-auth-devise

In my Spree Application i have created new role having name **sales_rep** and i want to give admin access to users having this role.

Here you can find my cancan ability file:

```
module Spree
  class SalesRepAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.respond_to?(:has_spree_role?) && user.has_spree_role?('sales_rep')
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
 end
end
```

but when i try to login via **admin** with **admin/login** URL it is not authenticating user other than admin.

Actually i want to override **Spree::Admin::UserSessionsController**'s create method in which **authenticate_spree_user!** is failing.

Is there any way to override **Spree::Admin::UserSessionsController**'s **authenticate_spree_user!** method so that having role of `sales_rep` can access this Admin panel.

Here is my method of controller:

```
 def create
   authenticate_spree_user!

  if spree_user_signed_in?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        flash[:success] = Spree.t(:logged_in_succesfully)

redirect_back_or_default(after_sign_in_path_for(spree_current_user))
    }
      format.js {
        user = resource.record
        render :json => {:ship_address => user.ship_address, :bill_address => user.bill_address}.to_json
    }
    end
  end
```

I just want to allow user having `sales_rep` role to login same as Admin do in Spree and for that i want to override **Spree::Admin::UserSessionsController**'s create method.

Is there any way to achieve this? How i can allow user having different role than admin to access panel.

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

You have to register your ability also.
Add `Spree::Ability.register_ability(Spree:: SalesRepAbility)` in spree.rb and restart you server